# Why mysql query return zero value?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT c.categoryName,
        note1.*,
        ((SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
          FROM notes
          WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'in')
        -
        (SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
         FROM notes
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'out')) as trxCount
       FROM notes AS note1 
       JOIN
         (SELECT noteDate
          FROM notes

          GROUP BY noteDate
          HAVING COUNT(noteDate) > 0)
        AS note2
          ON note1.noteDate = note2.noteDate
        JOIN category c
          ON c.categoryID = note1.categoryID
        ORDER BY note1.noteDate ASC
```

See on this:

```
((SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
          FROM notes
          WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'in')
        -
        (SELECT SUM(noteAmount)
         FROM notes
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(note1.noteDate, '%d-%m-%Y') AND noteType = 'out')) as trxCount
```

say if in one day there is only one income data (in) (no expenditure data). for example in = 15, and out = 0. in the query, I made [in - out] (15 - 0), but why did I get 0 instead of 15?

Comment: Click Edit. Click (?). Click advanced help. Read the formatting instructions. Edit your code so it is readable. Provide a [mcve] (some sample data would be useful).

Comment: In case of no data, the SUM function returns null value and that may be the reason you are getting this result. Try using COALESCE with SUM and check.

Comment: Oke, I Will try

Comment: Where I pass it?